# Larger check boxes that work cross-browser?

Tags: css, checkbox

I've seen many attempts at a solution. I'm trying to make the size of a check box larger with support for IE9+ major browsers.

The closest solution I came to used the transform scale property which worked but it looks pretty bad.

Also many of the questions on this topic were outdated.

Anyone have any success this this?

Thanks

Comment: You hate to create custom checkbox like in this tutorial: https://kyusuf.com/post/completely-css-custom-checkbox-radio-buttons-and-select-boxes

Comment: Thanks but that's not compatible with IE9

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way i imagine to customize checkbox via CSS only.

```css
label {
 display:inline-block;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}

div {
 position:relative;
}

input:checked + label {
 background:red;
}

input {
 opacity:0;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input id=chk type="checkbox">
 <label for="chk"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't take into account trying to leave the label intact.

Comment: Sorry? I really don't understand?